# PHP function without subname return true or false

Tags: php, function, return

I want to know if I can make a PHP function like function john(), without having any parameters. Do PHP functions always have to have a parameter like john($action)?

My script below won't work because of my empty action. Do I have to pass a NULL value as a parameter?

funcs.php

```
function is_customer_logged_in() {
    if($_COOKIE['HA_CUST_LOGIN'] == 1 && $_SESSION["loggedIn"]=="1"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

index.php

```
include("funcs.php");

if(is_customer_logged_in()) {
    echo 'logged in';
} else {
    echo 'not signed in';   
}
```

login-form.php

```
/* pseudo code, if form details
    match mySQL do this */

    $_SESSION["loggedIn"]="1";
    $_SESSION["userEmail"]=$username; //form variable
    $_SESSION["userID"]=$username; //form variable
    setcookie("HA_CUST_LOGIN", 1); // set a cookie and a session from a php salt db check
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="index.php"</script>';

    /* else go back to login-form.php */
```

Or do I have to return a string rather than a boolean?

Comment: can u pls paste error message here if u getting?

Comment: Just blank. I think Session_Start(); might be an issue. In Classic ASP, crappy session_start(); are not needed to make the code Ugly

Comment: Setting $_COOKIE['HA_CUST_LOGIN'] == 1 is a complete waste of time as it can be easily spoofed. Just  $_SESSION["loggedIn"]="1"; is enough

Comment: Is that secure enough though?

Comment: session_start() is only needed for when you want to enable session handling in your script. Otherwise, you can run scripts without session handling and save some processor time. Why take everything out of the toolbox when all you want is a screwdriver?

Comment: @HorusKol shame I cant downvote on that comment.

Comment: I was just responding to your 'crappy session_start(); are not needed to make the code Ugly'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a SESSION variable in the $_SESSION array. This variable will only be available on two conditions:

1. You have previously specified a value for $_SESSION['loggedIn']
2. (If the page/script has been requested again) you have called `session_start()` before trying to access the $_SESSION array() (and any output has been sent to the browser).

Even though you are using a COOKIE, you still need to call `session_start()` for your test to return evaluate true, because you have a logical AND in your IF statement:

```
if($_COOKIE['HA_CUST_LOGIN'] == 1 && $_SESSION["loggedIn"]=="1")
```

If session_start() has not been called, and the parameter $_SESSION["loggedIn"] has not been set, this IF statement will evaluate false. You should also be getting notices/warnings in your PHP logs (and in your browser if you are on a development machine) - if not, then you need to reconfigure your error reporting on you development machine.

Comment: So can I do this if(is_customer_logged_in()=="true")

Comment: not unless you start returning the string `'true'` from your function instead of sending boolean `true`

Comment: I have this working. I am just not confident with sessions for security. It feels uneasy to use if else headers now across the site for return member only pages.

Comment: Well - this is probably why you should be using some kind of page controller or front-facing controller. Otherwise, wrap all your security checks into a separate script and include that at the top of your pages - that way, you only have to write (and modify) the security logic in one place.

Comment: What is a front-facing controller. The security checks are being built into a function now via a global header include. I am just just not happy with SESSION. I am sure Facebook likes dont use a simple session? There must be lots of things that are checked.

Comment: it's more properly called just a [front controller](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=front-facing+controller&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#pq=php+controller&hl=en&cp=9&gs_id=6a&xhr=t&q=php+front+controller&tok=890Bs4vc4fC8aGtpgy47Ow&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&client=ubuntu&hs=N67&channel=fs&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=ph+pfront&aq=0l&aqi=g-l4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=6c809eb140267c9c&biw=1920&bih=940) - as for sessions, facebook like button scripts use the same strongly encrypted cookies that remember your login. But once you're in facebook, it will just use sessions.

Answer (score 2):

No you do not need a parameter in your function, since you didn't declare one in your function. Echo out the variables, I bet you didn't do `session_start()` before setting the session variables.

Comment: No I didn't actually. But I thought this is not needed since I am storing in a cookie too. Does session start need to go before EVERY code? Like at the top of funcs? As if I post the code with the redirect and echo the session it shows them via post. Not on the next page though. So they do not carry across on the redirect.

Comment: SESSION exist no matter what until you close the browser, it should still be there even after a redirect. Yes you do need the session_start() at the start before you do anything session related.